# Prevent double brackets when moving elements of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays (`a` and `b`) where each item has to move into another array (`c`)

I used the push/slice method to do this but **it adds brackets into each element**.

Here is the code:

```js
let a = [0, 6, 2, 0, 1, 1];
let b = [1, 3, 9, 0, 0, 1];
let c = [];
for (let i = 5; a.length > 0 || b.length > 0; i--) {
    c.push(a.splice(i, 1), b.splice(i, 1));
}
console.log(c) // I would like [element1, element2, etc]
```

Instead, is there another method (to replace `c.push(a.splice(i, 1), b.splice(i, 1))`) **which does not add brackets to each element** ?

Thanks!

Comment: `c.push(...a.splice(i, 1), ...b.splice(i, 1))`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why `.splice()` is even involved, but that's the problem: `.splice()` returns an array.

Comment: @Pointy - perhaps he wants to remove elements from a and b?

Comment: use `pop` instead of `splice` (`pop` doesn't need arguments)

Comment: @JaromandaX perhaps, but there's no explanation in the question.

Comment: `c.push(a.pop(), b.pop())`

Comment: @Pointy - yeah I know "p

Comment: removing the elements is a nice way of 'moving' them to ensure you get no doubles

Comment: @Thomas - a better one was given ... using .pop() instead, since your code always removes elements from the end of each array

Comment: using your code (and .pop) the result array is in reverse order ... is that a requirement?

Comment: Well it would be nice to keep original order...

Comment: Is it required to remove the elements from `a` and `b`? Or is the goal to just combine them in `c`?

Comment: If there's no need to empty out the `a` and `b` arrays, then simple array indexing is all that's necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on the comment "it'd be nice to keep them in the same order"

using another answers use of `.pop` .. use `.shift` to remove from beginning of array instead of end

also, you can use a while loop instead

```js
let a = [0, 6, 2, 0, 1, 1];
let b = [1, 3, 9, 0, 0, 1];
let c = [];
while(a.length > 0 || b.length) {
    c.push(a.shift(), b.shift());
}
console.log(c)
```

Of course, the above is fine if the array lengths are the same

But, based on your original code ... this works with uneven length arrays:

```js
let a = [0, 6, 2, 0, 1, 1];
let b = [1, 3, 9, 0, 0, 1, 99];
let c = [];
while(a.length > 0 || b.length) {
    c.push(...a.splice(0,1), ...b.splice(0, 1));
}
console.log(c)
```

Notice the splice is always at index 0 - to maintain order

Answer (score 1):

Using your exact answer all I did is access the `0` location in each spliced thing

```js
let a = [0, 6, 2, 0, 1, 1];
let b = [1, 3, 9, 0, 0, 1];
let c = [];
for (let i = 5; a.length > 0 || b.length > 0; i--) {
    c.push(a.splice(i, 1)[0], b.splice(i, 1)[0]);
}
console.log(c) // I would like [element1, element2, etc]
```

Comment: Why re-invent `Array.prototype.pop()`?

Comment: in questions aren't we supposed to adjust the OP's tried code towards the answer? There are several answers for this but it's the quickest tweak

Answer (score 0):

i already commented it, but is an answer, so here the answer

```js
let a = [0, 6, 2, 0, 1, 1];
let b = [1, 3, 9, 0, 0, 1];
let c = [];
for (let i = 5; a.length > 0 || b.length > 0; i--) {
    c.push(a.pop(), b.pop());
}
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `for` loop to go through both `a` and `b` at once and add the element, if there is one:

```js
let a = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14];
let b = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
let c = [];

for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
  if (i < a.length)
   c.push(a[i]);
  if (i < b.length)
   c.push(b[i]);
}

console.log(c);
```

This assumes the arrays would be of unequal length. If they are always going to be equal, then the `if` statements are not needed.

Alternative implementation for arrays of equal length:

```js
let a = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
let b = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11];
let c = a.flatMap((x, i) => [x, b[i]]);

console.log(c);
```

If `a` and `b` have to end up empty in the end, this can be just a simple:

```
a.length = 0; 
b.length = 0;
```

after `c` is created, instead of continually mutating the two arrays.

Answer (score -1):

The spread syntax is a new addition to the set of operators in JavaScript ES6. It takes in an iterable (e.g an array) and expands it into individual elements.

The spread syntax is commonly used to make shallow copies of JS objects. Using this operator makes the code concise and enhances its readability.

So , instead use :

```
let a = [0, 6, 2, 0, 1, 1];
let b = [1, 3, 9, 0, 0, 1];
let c = [...a,...b]
console.log(c)
```

Comment: its not what the op wants

Comment: the values wouldn't be interleaved

Comment: Thanks but this isn't really what I asked for

Comment: @C.O. This is not a link-only answer. There is no link in it at all. Why did you mark it as such?

Comment: I was being an idiot, the review que had a link to the SO post on top and I mistook that as the "answer" in question, sorry.